# Heroku hosting, with go-daddy domain name, you do not have access to the app? (heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an app that I currently have deployed through heroku. However I have a domain name that I purchased through go-daddy and i've been trying to sync up the domain name through go-daddy.

I've tried following the steps from this tutorial i found here. http://lifesforlearning.com/heroku-with-godaddy/

With a repository here: (I have further plans with this later, which is why it is a rails app) https://github.com/KDweber89/kdweber89

In my domain area with go-daddy i have things set up like this: [image]

However on the heroku side of things, when I try to run the command

```
 heroku domains:add www.kdweber89.com
```

I wind up with an error stating `You do not have access to the app`

I feel like I am missing a step, but I don't know what that step would be. Would anyone who has had some experience with this take a look? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: you can just add a domain in the dashboard of heroku if you go under settings on heroku.com and log in.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions that heroku posted ?: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: @KcUS_unico I added that on the dashboard.  But I am still getting the error.

Comment: @AlexanderLuna I get to step # 2 on the article you sent me and I get the same error that I do not have access to the app.  :(

Comment: Well, on heroku you just need to add the domain. Than with your domain provider add the CNAME. That's all. Since the error comes from heroku, can you push to heroku as normal, I mean are you using the correct credentials? Than all you need to do with heroku is to add this domain. Even in dashboard is enough. The rest of the work, e.g. CNAME you need to do with the domain provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the DNS settings:

   CNAME

   name  taget

   www   kdweber89.herokuapp.com

Save it and let give it some time to adjust everything it has to do then try again.

Comment: Hey bud, thank you so much for your help. It ended up being on the DNS side of things all along. (I think i got too focused on the heroku side of things failing on me). Thanks again for the steady guidance.

Comment: Sure, I'm glad it worked out. About DNS remember that it always takes times to propagate the changes. When you change your DNS file give it some time 1-2 hours at most. I got really desperate about DNS because I thought it was instantly and would change the DNS file every 5-10 mins which added just to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your CNAME with go daddy should be sth like this:

Host: *
Points to: kdweber89.herokuapp.com

to get the www. you cn use a permanent forwarding :

forward to:

www.kdweber89.com

wait a few minutes and it should be fine.